# Django Tastypie, how to search throught multiple modelresource?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm looking for a way to add a 'generic' search throught some of my ModelResource.
Using a 'v1' api, I would like to be able to query some of my ModelResources allready registered with this kind of url : /api/v1/?q='blabla'. Then I'd like to recover some of my ModelResourceS that could fill inside the query.

What approach do you think is the best one ?

I tried to build a GenericResource(Resource), with my own class reprensenting row data, without success. Would you have got some links to help me ?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a mobile application that we were creating an API for we created a similar "Search" type resource. Basically we agreed upon a set of types and some common fields that we would show in the search feed on the application. See the code below for the implementation:

```
class SearchObject(object):
def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, type=None):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.type = type


class SearchResource(Resource):
    id = fields.CharField(attribute='id')
    name = fields.CharField(attribute='name')
    type = fields.CharField(attribute='type')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'search'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        object_class = SearchObject
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        object_name = "search"
        include_resource_uri = False

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        kwargs = {}

        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.id
        else:
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj['id']

        return kwargs

    def get_object_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        query = bundle.request.GET.get('query', None)
        if not query:
            raise BadRequest("Missing query parameter")

        #Should use haystack to get a score and make just one query
        objects_one = ObjectOne.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).order_by('name').all)[:20]
        objects_two = ObjectTwo.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).order_by('name').all)[:20]
        objects_three = ObjectThree.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).order_by('name').all)[:20]

        # Sort the merged list alphabetically and just return the top 20
        return sorted(chain(objects_one, objects_two, objects_three), key=lambda instance: instance.identifier())[:20]

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return self.get_object_list(bundle, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why I get syntax error in the objectOne line? Should I have to do something more?